# Jquery: Error test after Ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax

Again, I have tried searching to prevent a duplicate but I think this error is due to my poor Jquery level.

My registration form uses the following Jquery:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form#registration').submit(function() {
        $('form#registration .error').remove();
        var hasError = false;
        $('.requiredField').each(function() {
            if($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
                var labelText = $(this).prev('label').text();
                $(this).parent().append('<span class="error">You forgot to enter your '+labelText+'</span>');
                $(this).addClass('inputError');
                hasError = true;
            } else if($(this).hasClass('email')) {
                var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
                if(!emailReg.test($.trim($(this).val()))) {
                    var labelText = $(this).prev('label').text();
                    $(this).parent().append('<span class="error">You have entered an invalid '+labelText+'</span>');
                    $(this).addClass('inputError');
                    hasError = true;
                } else {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        data: "email="+$(this).attr("value"),
                        url: "emailexists.php",
                        context: this,
                        success: function(data) {
                            if(data == 1) {
                                $(this).parent().append('<span class="error">This email already exists on file</span>');
                                hasError = true;
                            } 
                        }
                    });             
                }
            } else if($(this).hasClass('password')) {
                var regx = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/;
                if(!regx.test($.trim($(this).val()))) {
                    $(this).parent().append('<span class="error">Password can only contain alphanumerica characters A-Za-z0-9</span>');
                    hasError = true;
                } 
                var passlen = $.trim($(this).val().length);
                if(passlen < 7) {
                    $(this).parent().append('<span class="error">Password must be at least 7 characters in length</span>');
                    hasError = true;
                }
            } else if($(this).hasClass('cpassword')) {
                if($(this).val() != $('#password').val()) {
                    $(this).parent().append('<span class="error">Your passwords do not match</span>');
                    hasError = true;
                }
            }
        });

        **if(!hasError) {
            var formInput = $(this).serialize();
            $.post($(this).attr('action'),formInput, function(data) {
                $('form#registration').slideUp("fast", function() {                
                    $(this).before('<p class="tick">Thank you for registering with <font style="color:#ddbb88;">racingdatasheets.com</font>. You should receive a confirmation email shortly.</p>');**
                });
            });
        }

        return false;   
    });
});
```

My issue is the error test at the bottom which returns false if all other tests pass before my Ajax emailexists function returns a possible error. (I added 2 alerts and could see the error check at the bottom testing false prior to the emailexists setting hasError true. Am i just misunderstanding the asynchronous nature of Ajax and doing this all wrong?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to think about your order of operations..

You have 5 statements that are executed when the form is submitted, one immediately after the other.

Inside your `$('.requiredField').each(function() {` you are sending ajax requests, which are asynchronous, then continuing synchronously and inspecting the result (`hasError`).  This will unlikely have been set before the line `if(!hasError) {` is executed.

What you could do is store the requests in an array and user [jquery.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to check your `hasError` once they have all completed, something like this:

```
var requests = [];

...

    requests.push($.ajax(...))

...

$.when(requests).then(function () {
    if (!hasError) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Yes, that's what I thought and thought I had said. The ajax request was added after  I had the form working as I thought why even let them enter everything and then tell them the email is on file if I could make it 'smarter'.

Comment: Ok I suggest you look into storing your ajax requests in an array while looping, then using [jquery.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to execute your `hasError` check once they have all completed

Comment: I know we are supposed to avoid comments for 'Thanks'...but thanks Alex. I will try what you suggest.